# calculation the transmission range in meters based on tx power in dbm

Tags: omnet++

How can I calculate the transmission range in meters based on transmission power in dbm in the Inet of the Omnet++?
Does Inet 4.2 support this problem?
If no, how change the Inet 4.2 to support it?

Answer (score 2):

The success of a transmission does not only depend on the transmission power, but also on receiver sensitivity, attenuation, used error model, sender/receiver antenna configuration etc. You cannot directly calculate a distance from a given transmission power.

As for the second question: Yes, INET does model reception error once you configured all the above parameters. There are various models (in complexity) depending on how accurately you want to model the transmissions. If you are modeling higher level concepts (i.e. routing etc.) where you don't care about the low level details, you can use a very simple (UnitDiscRadio) model, where you can directly specify a range (instead of power) and all reception will be successful in that range and everything will fail above that.

If in doubt, consult the Wireless Tutorial on the INET site.

Comment: In theory, your answer is correct. But how can it be implemented in Omnet++?

Answer (score 0):

From an Antenna perspective, The range can be calculated using [Friss transmission formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friis_transmission_equation) in [Antenna theory](http://www.antenna-theory.com/basics/friis.php). This equation states that the received power at a distance R from the transmitter depend on,

- Directivity of the transmitting antenna
- Directivity of the receiving antenna
- Wavelength of the signal
  Also please note that their is an effect of [polarizaton loss factor (PLF)](http://www.antenna-theory.com/basics/polarization.php#polarization) which is a measure of how much power is loss due to alignment difference between Tx and Rx antenna modules.

Comment: In theory, your answer is correct. But how can it be implemented in Omnet++?